# How should I compare two different product price in php script?

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml, phpmyadmin

`$comapre` is an array with unique product ids passed on from previous page.so in the following page I want to look in the database using that `productid`, get information and compare the prices of the product corresponding to each `productid` from an `array($compare)`.

So far I can display the relevant product information using `productid` from `$compare(array`) in the following format

productid  | product name| price |
20_***_*__*_*_**|__iphone5_*_*|_529  |

i am using the code :

```
foreach($compare as $value) {

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_info` WHERE `productid`=".$value.""); 
    echo "<table border='1' bordercolor='#000066'> 
                <tr>
                    <th>productid</th>
                    <th>product name</th><br />
                    <th>price</th> 
                </tr>"; 

    while ($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5FFFF'>";
            echo "<td>". $query_row['productid']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $query_row['title']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $query_row['price']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }           
    echo "</table>";    
}
```

Please give me any suggestion how to compare the price of each product and say like "productA is £*_* cheaper than productB" something similar to that would also work.please help.

Comment: Just as a an unrelated tip, don't use mysql_query anymore, use either MySQLi or PDO, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: How is price stored in the database?

Comment: price is stored using INSERT INTO database. Actually i have an upload page on website from where i can upload data directly into database from webpage. so price is already stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the prices to a new array say product_prices[].

```
$product_prices['$productID'] = $query_row['price'];
```

You can then sort this array by increasing/decreasing order of prices and then subtract prices between individual keys.

How you work with the product_prices array is totally left to you and the use case that you have.

Comment: hey i thought i've got the idea but actually i've got little stuck with the array. when i created a new array i got array with prices but coudn't go backto the relevent productid for that price. is that clear (i'm sorry my explanation is horrible) but any suggestion?? i want to compare price and then want to display that product a is cheaper than product b. something like that.any hints??

Comment: Important thing while creating the new array is the key for every element in the array should be productID instead of 0,1,2...

Answer (score 0):

UNRELATED - you could get rid of that foreach loop by using mysql's IN clause.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_info` WHERE `productid` IN (.join(",", $value).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE price_a <= price_b;
```